# Java code for SVN to add and commit the Files into server

Tags: java, svn, tortoisesvn

I am writing java code which add and commits the files to SVN server using java

```
String str="svn add D:/dump1/dumpo/CVE./*";

Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(str);

String str1="svm commit -m 'addingfile';

Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(str1);
```

above is the code which add the files to SVN server but not commiting,

But after commiting only these files can reflect into the SVN server with a Version number.

I want to add and commit the files at a time.

I want to add and commit the files or folders at a time using java code.

Please can you help me to reslove the same.

Comment: `String str1="svm commit -m 'addingfile';` is it a spelling mistake? Maybe, you want `String str1="svn commit -m 'addingfile'";`

Comment: are you saying that the `svn add ...` command works fine, but not the `svn commit ...` command?

Comment: Yes anirvan...because i have added the file and run the command in console mode by typing "svn commit -m 'aading'" and the files where added into the SVN server. thats is before adding the files , files will never commit to the SVN

Comment: I corrected the str1, Still its giving the same error.

Comment: Can i add both the commands and run in a single command using Runtime.getRuntime().exec(); method?

Comment: Hey can you tell me what way you are following to commit code/file/folder to svn using java?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your commit is happening too fast after the add.  You might need to wait some time between calls.  Check this out:

http://www.techiegyan.com/2008/06/04/how-to-run-external-exeprogram-from-java/